# ForEach will not alter/change items in list C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm pretty sure this has worked before in some code I have written, not sure what I am missing here.

The following code does not change the `string` values in my list. Why?

```
var items = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
items.ForEach(item => item = (!chkBox1.Checked) ? "move " + item : "move -check " + item);
```

**EDIT** : Just to clarify, the list remains the same as when it was created.

**EDIT** : Apologies, the items list (listBox1.Items) contains alphanumeric strings as follows.

`J00123456`

`J00123344`

`J00123458`

Also, just to confirm, I have successfully done this with a custom list of T (shown below), which is why I thought it would work here.

```
var tapes = new List<TapeInfo>();
... //Populated list
tapes.ForEach(x => x.vItem = "tapelib 3592 -eject " + x.vItem);  //Works here
```

Comment: What is the exact error or exception that you are getting here ?

Comment: @HarveySpecter _The following code does not change the string_

Comment: Which string are you comparing with? the listbox items? your `ToList` is making a copy

Comment: @HarveySpecter I edited my initial question. No error, just receiving the same result, I expect an altered list.

Comment: I cannot properly answer the question unless I know what is inside Items. Is it just string or something else?

Comment: [see my comment to motcke's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911734/foreach-will-not-alter-items-in-list-c-sharp/29911860?noredirect=1#comment47946877_29912027)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the `Select` function if you want to get a different result.

```
var items = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
listBox1.Items = items.Select(item => (!chkBox1.Checked) ? "move " + item : "move -check " + item).ToList();
```

The `ForEach` function can do something according to a collection value, but can't do it to the values themselves.

The `Select` function will create a new collection according to the given collection.

**Edit**

About your edit of successfully changing values by using

```
tapes.ForEach(x => x.vItem = "tapelib 3592 -eject " + x.vItem);
```

You need to understand how **passing argument by value/reference** works.

In c#, when writing `var obj1 = new object()`, `obj1` is a pointer to the `new object()` that exists on the [heap](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx?ArticleID=9adb0e3c-b3f6-40b5-98b5-413b6d348b91).

When you pass `obj1` to a function `public void Foo(object obj) { //... }` by calling `Foo(obj1)`, the function will get the parameter as **new** pointer to the **same** `object` on the heap.

Therefore, when you use ForeEach on the object itself,

```
object.ForEach(obj => obj = new object()) // No changed outside the Foreach
```

only the new pointer will be changed and it will point on a new object but the original pointer isn't changed.

But if you use it on an inner object,

```
object.ForEach(obj => obj.InnerObject = new object()) // Changed outside the Foreach
```

this will change the pointed inner object and the inner object will be changed.

Comment: Just to clarify: foreach can't re-assign the values, but if the value is an object, it can change it's properties.

Answer (score 6):

`string`s are immutable, so they cannot be changed. Assigning another value to that variable only changes that variable (difference between call-by-reference and call-by-value).

When you use the `ForEach`-method, you actually iterate over your `items`-list using the `item`-variable declared in your lambda-expression. Assigning a different value to that variable, cannot change the list.

And to have it clear what my first sentence means: You cannot change the value of your variable, because it's immutable, so you assign the variable, which cannot take affect to the list.

Comment: While this is true, it is not applicable in this case.

Comment: He assumes, that when he assigns another value to the variable using to iterate over `items`, he will change the list. So this IS applicable.

Comment: Thats correct, I just realised this. I have added a code sample (above) where this works with a custom list.

Comment: @MickIlovski A bit less elegant way could have been to use a for-loop and actually changing the list. Could be a tiny bit faster, but with several line of code more.

Comment: @Euphoric My answer is not simply about the problem, but concerning what I believe the poster actually means/thinks. Finding X instead of solving Y.

Answer (score 4):

Foreach simply can't do it, since `item` is a local variable within the loop's scope.
What you have is basically the same as using the long version:

```
foreach(string item in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList())
{
    item = (!chkBox1.Checked) ? "move " + item : "move -check " + item;
}
```

you can use a for loop to achieve your goal:

```
string Item;
for(var i=0;i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Item = listBox1.Items[i].ToString(); // Listbox Items are objects, so you need to use ToString() here
    listBox1.Items[i] = (chkBox1.Checked) ? "move -check " + Item : "move " + Item;
}
```

That's assuming, of course, that the items are and should be strings. I've also improved readability of your ternary condition.

Comment: The reason behind this is that .NET does not allow lambdas to have a ref parameter. Otherwise, a `ForEach` overload working on `IList<T>` could easily exist.

Comment: Actually, it can't be done in the long version of foreach as well, so while your statement about ref parameters in lamdba expressions is true, it's not the actual reason why it's not working.

Comment: Please do not confuse the language construct `foreach` and the library method `ForEach`. They are by no means connected except that they have a similar semantics.

Comment: @Georg Point taken. you're correct, this confusion was my mistake.